# sizeWithAttributes causes crash on ios 6. Works in ios 7

Tags: ios6, ios7

Since the sizeWithFont method is now deprecated I wanted to try the sizeWithAttributes which works as expected when running ios 7. But when I run it on ios 6 it causes a crash, and I can see that by looking at the header which looks like this.

```
- (CGSize)sizeWithAttributes:(NSDictionary *)attrs NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0);
```

Since the sizeWithAttributes came from another category which is removed now I can't use it in ios 6 and under.

What can I do about it? I can use sizeWithFont: if target is < ios 7, but there must be a reason that it has been deprecated, thus I want to avoid it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It did not exist on iOS 6 so I guess that is why you get a crash. It is in OSX 10.8 and 10.9.